# Batch file to delete files from wildcard folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, wildcards

How do I create a batch file that deletes files from multiple directories?

```
D:\L1\asdasda\L3\*.txt
D:\L1\dfghfghfh\L3\*.txt
D:\L1\tyutyugj\L3\*.txt
D:\L1\ytrtyrty\L3\*.txt
```

Like:

```
D:
del "d:\L1\*\L3\*.txt"
```

**Note by barlop- questioner adds-**

I have about a hundred of those directories. I do not want to delete the Folders, only the files. All of them have a L3 Folder, and they all contain some files with the same extension. Those are just temporary files, but it does not delete automatically.

Comment: you haven't stated the error you get

Comment: you can say `del a.a b.b`

Comment: Are the "&#42;" really the file name (deleting that works here) or is that only some unnecessary HTML markup (then please write just the real file name)?

Comment: Sorry, previously it couldn't display the * properly, therefore I used a HTML code to display (*). But I'm not sure why it works now.

Comment: oh you want like an rmdir with a wildcard. I guess what i'd do is not that.. I'd get a list of the files that you want to delete, into a file. Then i'd get the word "del " before them, and make that file a batch file and run it. That's quite safe too 'cos then you see exactly what would be getting deleted. You can open the list of files in notepad++ and find the beginning of each line with ^ and replace it with "del "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### BATCH FILE TO DELETE FROM SUBFOLDERS WITH DIFFERENT NAMES DYNAMICALLY USING WILDCARD FOR SUBFOLDER NAMES

> Batch file to delete files from wildcard folder

Here's an easy and simple batch script example that I use to complete this type of task all the time, I plugged in the variable folder paths to suit your needs as you describe:

### SAMPLE BATCH SCRIPT

***(Set your variable root folder and subfolder up top, and the `FOR /D`  and `FOR` loops iterate accordingly to do the rest of the magic traversing the directory as the logic specifies and completes the `DEL /Q /F` command for the `*.txt` files)***

```
@ECHO ON

SET SourceDir=D:\L1
SET SourceSubDir=L3

:: --// note the asterisk wildcard after SourceDir in the first FOR /D loop using X as the variable
:: --// note the X variable appended to the beginning of the second FOR (no /D switch here) loop in the SET part using Y as the variable
FOR /D %%X IN ("%SourceDir%\*") DO FOR %%Y IN ("%%~X\%SourceSubDir%\*.txt") DO DEL /Q /F "%%~Y"
GOTO EOF
```

**NOTE:** *If you plan to run this with a copy and paste manually in the command prompt, then the variables in the* `FOR` *loops need to have one of the percent signs removed in all parts so use the below for that part if you're running this manually with a copy and paste rather than in a batch script and executing that which is how the above example will work.*

```
FOR /D %X IN ("%SourceDir%\*") DO FOR %Y IN ("%~X\%SourceSubDir%\*.txt") DO DEL /Q /F "%~Y"
```

---

### FURTHER DETAIL AND RESEACH

*(Type in* `FOR /?` *in Windows Command Prompt to see this detail)*

***FOR (with no switch)***

```
Runs a specified command for each file in a set of files.

FOR %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]

  %variable  Specifies a single letter replaceable parameter.
  (set)      Specifies a set of one or more files.  Wildcards may be used.
  command    Specifies the command to carry out for each file.
  command-parameters
             Specifies parameters or switches for the specified command.

To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different
from %I.

If Command Extensions are enabled, the following additional
forms of the FOR command are supported:
```

***FOR /D***

```
FOR /D %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]

    If set contains wildcards, then specifies to match against directory
    names instead of file names.
```

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting your line \L1\*\L3\*.  As: For a given directory L1 find all the subdirectories that have a subdirectory  L3 and delete all the files in it.

A script has to be written to walk the directory structure.
It not easily doable as a batch file you may have to use Perl or  powershell which  have ways of getting list of directories or files and then doing a repeated action on them.

In pseudo code

```
Get list directories
For each dir 
  Cd into it
  Check if The dir L3 exists
  If it does then del .\L3\*.* 
  Go back up a level
Next dir
```

I will think about this and did this in batch file code although
I am thinking of redoing it in powershell just to see the difference.

Ok I thought about it

This batch file will walk directory structure from where is is run from
and delete the content of any directory that has the name "L3".

```
@echo off
for /r %%d in (*) do call :process "%%d"
goto :eof

:process
pushd "%~dp1"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('cd') do (
     set foldername=%%~nxA
    )
if "%foldername%"=="L3" del/q *.*
popd
goto :eof
```

It may be possible to make is simpler but the action of getting just the current directory name is messy (the for loop in process section)

If a directory starts out like this

```
└───L1
    │   1.dat
    │
    ├───Alice
    │   │   9.dat
    │   │
    │   └───L3
    │           c.dat
    │           d.dat
    │
    ├───Bob
    │       6.dat
    │
    ├───Carole
    │   │   2.dat
    │   │
    │   └───L3
    │           a.dat
    │           b.dat
    │
    └───Ted
            6.dat
```

run cleantree should make look like this

```
└───L1
    │   1.dat
    │
    ├───Alice
    │   │   9.dat
    │   │
    │   └───L3
    ├───Bob
    │       6.dat
    │
    ├───Carole
    │   │   2.dat
    │   │
    │   └───L3
    └───Ted
            6.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %G in ('dir /ad /b D:\L1\') do del D:\L1\%G\L3\*.txt
```

`for /f` runs following do command on all files in set

`%G in ('dir /ad /b D:\L1\')` variable set as the bare format for each folder within given directory

delete command using set %G value & wildcard for the directory

---

**Test Run First**

run with echo to print to the console the commands that will run to test the command without actually running it:

```
for /f %G in ('dir /ad /b D:\L1\') do echo del D:\L1\%G\L3\*.txt
```